# Why is the function defined by $f(x_1,x_2)=0$ when $x_1=0$, and $x_2$ when $x_1\neq 0$ not regular?

Tags: functions, algebraic-geometry

I'm having trouble understanding what should be a straight forward example.

Suppose $X\subseteq\mathbb{A}^2_k$ is cut out by the equation $x_1(x_2^2-x_1)=0$. Define a function $f:X\to k$ (here $k=\bar{k}$ is a field) by $f(x_1,x_2)=0$ if $x_1=0$, and $f(x_1,x_2)=x_2$ if $x_1\neq 0$. Then $f$ is not regular, but $f^2$ is.

Can anybody explain how to see this?

I was thinking if $x_1\neq 0$, then $x_2=\pm\sqrt{x_1}$ in $X$, so $f(x_1,x_2)=0$ if $x_1=0$, and $f(x_1,x_2)=\pm\sqrt{x_1}$ otherwise? I'm not sure about the sign, but this doesn't seem like it could be written as a polynomial, so $f$ is not regular? On the other hand, $f^2$ is defined by $f(x_1,x_2)^2=0$ when $x_1=0$, and $f(x_1,x_2)^2=x^2_2=x_1$ when $x_1\neq 0$? So does this just mean $f(x_1,x_2)^2=x_1$, which is a polynomial function, so $f^2$ is regular?

I just started reading some basics on my own recently, so I'm not too comfortable with the machinery yet.

Comment: You're on the right track. You've spotted the main idea. Now all you have to do is formalize it. I'm not sure how much you've already learned but here's a way to write this out. X is affine and it's ring of global sections is just $k[x,y]/(x_{1}(x_{2}^{2} - x_{1})).$ Suppose $g$ is some element in this ring which restricts to $x_{2}$ under localization at $x_{1}$. Since polynomials are continuous, this means that it must agree with the global section $x_{2}$ everywhere. So now, you need to show that $x_{2}$ is not $0$ at $x_{1}$ i.e. $x_{2}$ is not contained in the ideal generated by $x_{1}$.